# How to create PagePreview with more than one page using PDFsharp?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp

I am using [PDFsharp](http://www.pdfsharp.net/) to create PDF files in my C# application. It's working very good, but I did not find out how to create preview with more than one page. I have no trouble creating and saving documents with multiple pages, also embedding `PagePreview` into my Form is working.

But **how do I display** (and draw on) **more than one page** in the Preview?

Is there a way to pass another `XGraphics` object to associated `RenderEvent` function (that would be created from second page in document (`XGraphics.FromPdfPage(...)`))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RenderEvent must know which page to render.
Your application must know how many pages there are and which page is the current page.

We are using MigraDoc to create PDF files and the preview handles multiple pages automatically.

Comment: hi would you pls take a look at this one ....pls http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953471/system-crashing-when-the-print-button-is-clicked