# creating thread using c#

Tags: c#, multithreading

If I have a created a object like this

```
memberdetail md = new memberdetail(arg0, arg1, arg3)
```

how can I create a thread for the md object?

```
Thread t = new Thread((md));
t.Start();
```

is not working. Thx

Comment: In this scenario, you need to point your thread to method in your md instance. The ThreadStart needs to point to a method, not an "object".

Comment: Are you trying to pass md as a parameter to a Thread?  If so you would need to use a Parameterized ThreadStart  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163600.aspx.

Comment: You can't create a thread for an object; you’d rather define a task (method) which you want to run in separate thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass the object into the thread on start, do this:

```
public class Work
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        memberdetail md = new memberdetail(arg0, arg1, arg3)
        Thread newThread = new Thread(Work.DoWork);

        // Use the overload of the Start method that has a
        // parameter of type Object.
        newThread.Start(md);
    }

    public static void DoWork(object data)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Static thread procedure. Data='{0}'", data);
        // You can convert it here
        memberdetail md = data as memberdetail;
        if(md != null)
        {
           // Use md
        }
    }
}
```

See [Thread.Start Method (Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x4c42hc.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

You don't start a thread on an *object*, but rather a *method*:

```
memberdetail md = new memberdetail(arg0, arg1, arg3);
Thread t = new Thread(md.DoSomething);   
t.Start();
```

Comment: You can start a Thread with a specific object-method but there is no link between thread and object whatsoever.

Comment: Yup! Rightly said. Updated my answer to remove this implying statement.

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass the object's method to the Thread's constructor as below,

```
Thread t = new Thread(md.SomeFn);
t.Start();
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173178(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. You do not create a Thread for an object. Threads are separate.
2. In most cases you should not be using Threads (anymore). Look at ThreadPool and Tasks (TPL library).

Comment: +1 for point 3, The thread pool usually has significant advantages to hand rolling.

Comment: Would any one pls take a look at this question if you know any thing pls give me any suggestions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6953471/system-crashing-when-the-print-button-is-clicked

Answer (score 1):

Try this if all you want to do is create multiple objects in different threads.

```
for(int i = 0, i < numThreads; i++)
    (new Thread( () => 
        { memberdetail md = new memberdetail(arg0, arg1, arg3) }).start()
```

Any other actions you want to perform you can do inside the body of the lambda e.g.

```
for(int i = 0, i < numThreads; i++)
    (new Thread( () => 
        {
            memberdetail md = new memberdetail(arg0, arg1, arg3);
            md.ActionOne();
            md.ActionTwo();
            //Some other actions...
        }).start()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't create a thread for objects per se. You can pass an instance of a delegate to be invoked on the thread.

like on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.aspx).

Threads do functions not, contain objects.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem so that the application can manage the thread, and make sure memberdetail inherits from object.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza.aspx

```
   memberdetail md = new memberdetail(arg0, arg1, arg3)
   ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWork, md);

    private void DoWork(object state)
    {
       if (state is memberdetail)
       {
         var md= state as memberdetail;    
         //DO something with md
       }
    }
```